# How do i know, which Peer did the Transaction in Hyperledger Fabric Go?

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am working on getting a transaction id info, which will give the peer details for the transaction. Currently, I am able to retrieve the History for a key, which gives me the list of transaction committed to that key.

**MyCode:**

```
historyRes, err := stub.GetHistoryForKey(userNameIndexKey)

if err != nil {
    return shim.Error(fmt.Sprintf("Unable to get History key from the ledger: %v", err))
}

for historyRes.HasNext() {

    history, errIt := historyRes.Next()

    if errIt != nil {
        return shim.Error(fmt.Sprintf("Unable to retrieve history in the ledger: %v", errIt))
    }

    deleted := history.GetIsDelete()

    ds := strconv.FormatBool(deleted)

    fmt.Println("History TxId = "+history.GetTxId()+" --  Delete = "+ds)
 }
```

**Output**

```
History TxId = 78c8d17c668d7a9df8373fd85df4fc398388976a1c642753bbf73abc5c648dd8 -- Deleted = false

History TxId = 102bbb64a7ca93367334a8c98f1f7be17e6a8d5277f0167c73da47072d302fa3 -- Deleted = true
```

But I don't know, which peer did this transaction. Is there any API available in **fabric-sdk-go** to retrieve peer info for a transaction id.

please suggest me some solution.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for the peer that did the transaction or the client/member identity with which the transaction was signed and broadcasted for endorsing? Cuz, the peers are mostly involved in simulating and endorsing the transactions and they never propose the transaction.

Comment: I am not sure but mostly, i want to know , which organization did the transaction among all the available org in a network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call `stub.GetHistoryForKey(userNameIndexKey)` will query the state database and not the ledger (channel). The information about the identity who made the transaction is stored in the block.

I have implemented the same thing with NodeJS SDK. However, Go SDK too contains similar API calls. The following steps worked for me:

1. Using your SDK, get the transactionId
2. Use the SDK function for querying block by transactionId. References [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/blob/48690b259926e9b25bb00443e32bd17f8a14952c/pkg/client/ledger/ledger.go#L194).
3. At this step, you'll get the block. Now the identity of the submitter is located within this block. Hints: Payload -> Header -> Signature Header -> Creater -> IdBytes.
4. These identity bytes are the X509 certs of the submitter. You can read the certificate info to find out which member did submit this transaction. The subject and OUs will indicate the Organization of the peer that did the transaction.

Comment: one more thing, i received the block by txid but how to read the blockheader hash byte array in go

Comment: Do you mean to say the identity byte array?

Comment: in this post, i have specified , please check :   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56961434/how-to-read-block-data-received-by-transaction-id-in-hyperledger-fabric-go

Comment: yes i am getting the byte array but not able to see the data

Comment: If you just need the MSP_ID then you can get that from Payload -> Header -> Signature Header -> Creater -> Msp Id. However, if you need the exact identity of that signed the transaction, you'll need to use some utility to parse IdBytes which is a PEM string to the certificate. I used one of the utilities available in node to convert this pem string to X509 format certificate. Not much aware about syntax/semantics of GoLang yet, however, I'm sure there might be some utility to help you convert PEM string to X509 Certificate.